# How can we save/download file that not visible to user in android / ios?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, path, storage

I am using [Dio Package](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) for downloading files and using the [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package to get the system path to save files.

```
Directory? appDocumentsDirectory =
    Platform.isIOS ? await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()  : await getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

but I heard that the getAppicationDocuments directory and External Storage in android are visible to the user so how can I make it invisible?

Answer (score 0):

You may like to use **Flutter Secure Storage** it stores encrypted file that is **not accessible** by the end-user except if the user has **rooted the device**.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage

Comment: can we save music files in it? 100 music files? is there any limit ?

Comment: for that please go with the documentation first. it may have a limitation.

Comment: yes, that's why I need to store it within the app store but I don't know how we can access it within the app storage.